# Vertical align using transform: translateY(-50%); inside absolutely positioned div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically centre a h2 inside a div that is absolutely positioned with a height of 50% using the following code:

```
#owl-demo h2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Works fine on Chrome, but the h2 disappears in Safari IOS unless I set the h2 to be positioned absolute and then I can't centre the text with text-align.

Any help much appreciated, I've been trying to make this work all day.

**Edit:** So it looks like the height 50% is the problem on the parent div, if I remove it the text appears in IOS.
I'm trying to achieve an overlay that covers 50% of the thumbnail height is there another way to get it to cover 50% of the thumbnail?

```
#owl-demo  .thumb-overlay {
    text-align: center;
    height: 50%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
z-index: 9999;
opacity:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

#owl-demo  .thumb-overlay:hover {
    opacity:0.75;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 75);
    transition:opacity 0.25s;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.25s;
}

.touch #owl-demo  .thumb-overlay,  {
    opacity:1;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 1);
}

#owl-demo h2 {
font-size: .875em;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: $white;
}
```

Comment: HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/5cn5s/

Looks like it's the height that is causing the issue looking for another way to set the height of the overlay to 50%, any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/5cn5s/

Comment: that fiddle is not good.. give another one without PHP inside HTML

Comment: Sorry, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/5cn5s/10/

Comment: -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); fixed it for me, thanks for this

Answer (score 8):

The following is working for me in safari (5.1.7)

```
#owl-demo h2 {
 font-size: 1em;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
 transform: translateY(100%);
 color: white;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/5cn5s/14/)

As for other ways, since you can make use of `::before` pseudo element for aligning :

```
#owl-demo .thumb-overlay::before {
content:"";
display:block;
height:30%;
```

}

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/5cn5s/13/)

Comment: That solution doesn't actually vertically centre the text.

Comment: @user2204755 check the second one.

Comment: Actually using the :before element works ok on a single line but not a multi-line title.

Comment: The major problem is that you are using `<h2>` which is a block element to which browsers apply margin, padding etc so the actual size of the block won't be what you're expecting.. if you use a `<span>` `<p>` and style it, it'll be much easier.
plus the question was abt fixing the problem in safari, you never said anything about multilines.. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution today to solve this issue with mobile safari & mobile chrome.

Use the same code you already have for the CSS h2 in your example, except put **vertical-align:top;**

This seems to fix the translateY on mobile Safari.  I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Good question... I'm not sure, would like to know though.

Answer (score 3):

```
.selector {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: it would be more helpful if you also provided a link to it working on jsFiddle.net

Comment: you can take it dawn to flex-box all you need is set the parent to {display:flex} and child {margin:auto} here is can i use to see the support on browsers https://caniuse.com/#search=flex-box  hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Prefixes should do the trick:

```
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```